# Single windows SPN for multiple URLs?

Tags: windows, dns, single-sign-on

For example, we have multiple web servers on non-windows machines, that are accessed by windows domain users.
All servers are registered in that same windows domain DNS as well.
For binary applications, that need access to that servers, we have one SPN in keytab, since windows SSPI API can give service ticket for any arbitrary string.
But when it comes to browser requests, browsers are going to request tickets for SPNs based on different URLs.
Is there a way to keep the same single SPN by configuring some sort of trust on domain level or something like that?

Update: while experimenting with ktpass, I see that service key in keytab does not depend on SPN, it depends just on bound account. So technically it is enough to just add SPNs to account and do not check principal with keytab's one on service side